# Rewrite a date in a filename to ISO 8601 then set created to same date

Tags: macos, zsh

This is in zsh on a Mac. I need to rename a file `Statement for Apr 14, 2023.pdf` as `Reported on 2023-04-14T000000.000Z`, then I need to set the file's created date to the ISO date in the new filename. The process feeds the input filename as `$1` .

If it were PowerShell, I'd check $1 against an array of 3-letter month names and numbers and set $mon on match, then I'd take the numbers after the month name and before the comma and set a two-digit $day, then grab the last four numbers of $1 and set $year. I'd build `$isodate` as `$($year)-$($month)-$($day)T000000.000Z` and build it into a string to rename $1. Then I'd gci $1's creation property using $isodate.

But I'm not sure how do all of that manipulation in zsh. Can I get a boost? Thank you!

Comment: Note that bash and zsh are two different shells. _Pick one_. (Also, the version matters: Apple's default bash is too old to have time-handling primitives built into modern releases; since they refuse to use any version of bash licensed under GPLv3 terms, Apple is shipping a bash from the 3.2 release series that started in 2006).

Comment: BTW, one very much can run powershell on MacOS. I install it there (via [Nix](https://nixos.org/)) regularly.

Comment: Okay. Using Apple's older bash 3 actually works in your favor insofar as it means you can't use newer features that are bash-specific, so you'll probably end up with something that works with zsh as well (despite being a bit slower than it would be if doing the logic inside the interpreter). One last question: Do you have GNU date installed, or only Apple's default (BSD-flavored) `date` command?

Comment: Thank you, @CharlesDuffy . First stack post, fighting with the interface a little. 

I'll be going with zsh 5.9 (arm-apple-darwin21.3.0) running on a MacOS 13.3.1 system.

MS PS is in the environment, but I want to use zsh for this and I want to learn a little on the way.

Comment: (Hmm. I know bash's built-in regex syntax, but don't know zsh's equivalent; going to need to take a minute to look it up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zsh (or newer versions of bash than Apple supports), you have *associative arrays* -- what other languages might call dicts or maps.

```
declare -A months=( [Jan]=1 [Feb]=2 [Mar]=3 [Apr]=4 [May]=5 [Jun]=6 [Jul]=7 [Aug]=8 [Sep]=9 [Oct]=10 [Nov]=11 [Dec]=12 )

date_regex='^(.*)(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([[:digit:]]+), ([[:digit:]]{4})(.*)'

rename_date() {
  local prefix suffix isodate
  if [[ $1 =~ $date_regex ]]; then
    prefix=${match[1]}
    isodate=$(printf '%04d-%02d-%02dT0000.000Z' "${match[4]}" "${months[${match[2]}]}" "${match[3]}")
    suffix=${match[5]}
    printf 'in:  %s\nout: %s\n' "$1" "${prefix}${isodate}${suffix}" >&2
    : mv -- "$1" "${prefix}${isodate}${suffix}" # uncomment at will
  else
    printf 'Error: %q did not match regex\n' "$1" >&2
  fi
}
```

With the above defined, running:

```
rename_date 'Statement for Apr 14, 2023.pdf'
```

properly emits:

```
in:  Statement for Apr 14, 2023.pdf
out: Statement for 2023-04-14T0000.000Z.pdf
```

To adapt this to bash, you would change `match` to `BASH_REMATCH`. (You could also use `printf -v isodate ...` instead of `isodate=$(printf ...)` for improved performance).

Answer (score 1):

The `strftime` and `strptime` system functions are available in `zsh` via the `zsh/datetime` module, and can be used to parse and format dates:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
zmodload zsh/datetime

renameWithDate() {
    local inFmt='Statement for %b %d, %Y.pdf'
    local outFmt='Reported on %FT000000.000Z.pdf'
    local TZ=UTC
    local fileTime=
    local newName=

    strftime -s fileTime -r -- ${inFmt:?} ${1:?}
    strftime -s newName -- ${outFmt:?} ${fileTime:?}
    mv -v -- $1 ${newName:?}
    touch -c -d "$(strftime '%FT00:00:00Z' $fileTime)" $newName
    # SetFile -d "$(strftime '%m/%d/%Y' $fileTime)" $newName
}

for fl in Statement*.pdf; do
    renameWithDate $fl
done
```

Some notes:

- `strftime -s <var> -r <fmt> <str>`: with `-r`, this is a call to [`strptime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strptime.3.html) to parse the string based on the value in `<fmt>`. The result is the number of seconds since the 'epoch', and is stored in `<var>`.
- `strftime -s <var> <fmt> <etime>`: calls [strftime](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strftime.3.html) to format the time represented by the epoch time `<etime>` based on `<fmt>`, and puts the string in `<var>`.
- `TZ=UTC`:  sets the timezone for the strftime calls. As long as the `strptime` and `strftime` calls share the same timezone they should match up, but setting `TZ` eliminates any ambiguity.
- `mv`: renames the file.
- `touch -d ...`: sets the modification and access timestamps of the file. While `touch` will change the creation time in some cases, it does not have an option for setting that time directly.
- `SetFile -d ...`: sets the creation time of the file. It's commented out because a) it needs to be installed with the [Xcode command line tools](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/4.html), and b) it's now marked as deprecated.  There's some more info about setting the creation time in macOS [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99536) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/445378). TL;DR: it's complicated.

If the user's locale doesn't match the locale used for the dates in the file names, you may have to set it in the function. Also, the man pages for `strftime` and `strptime` say they do not always work correctly with multi-byte strings.  The function worked fine in some tests with UTF-8 characters, but that is something to check.

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer. Outstanding. I've got a lot to learn!